# Show every convex function is continuous on the interior of it's domain (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, convex-analysis

Let $f: \mathcal X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a convex function. Show that $f$ is continuous on the interior of $\mathcal X$.

**What I've tried**

Originally I tried to show this starting from the definition of continuity based on the inverse mapping of open sets, but I found it difficult to get anything concrete.

Here is my proof based on contradiction:

If $f$ is not continuous on the interior of it's domain, then there is a point $x \in \text{int}\,\mathcal X$ and positive constant $\epsilon$ such that for all neighborhoods $N(x)$ of $x$ there is another point $x' \in N(x)$ which has $|f(x') - f(x)| > \epsilon$.

There are four possible cases:

1. $x$ is a discontinuity of the second kind and has $f(x) < f(p) - \epsilon$ for $p$ close enough to $x$.
2. $x$ is a discontinuity of the second kind and has $f(x) > f(p) + \epsilon$ for $p$ close enough to $x$.
3. $x$ is a discontinuity of the first kind and has $f(x) < f(p) - \epsilon$ for $p$ along a ray starting at $x$.
4. $x$ is a discontinuity of the first kind and has $f(x) > f(p) + \epsilon$ for $p$ along a ray starting at $x$.

I claim that for each of these cases we have a contradiction which arises from the definition of convexity:
$$f(\lambda \, x_1 + (1-\lambda)\, x_2) \leq \lambda\, f(x_1) + (1-\lambda)\, f(x_2)$$

for every $x_1, x_2 \in \mathcal X$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

I'll only show the first case here, but the remaining are similar.

Starting from the definition of convexity and our hypothesis from case 1:

$$f(\lambda \, p + (1-\lambda)\, x) \leq \lambda\, f(p) + (1-\lambda)\, f(x) \leq f(x) - \epsilon (1-\lambda)$$

for $x$ the point of discontinuity and $p$ some point satisfying the condition in 1. This holds for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Rearranging we have:

$$f(x) \geq f(\lambda \, p + (1-\lambda)\, x) + \epsilon (1-\lambda)$$

Since $\lambda$ is arbitrary in $[0,1]$, we can choose it such that the condition in case 1 is contradicted.

I could use some feedback on my reasoning. Maybe the cases I have given might implicitly assume that $f$ is continuous, but I think they can be shown just using the definition of continuity (for example if $\mathcal X = \mathbb R$ then we can say that the slope function of $f$ is increasing so that such a set of points $p$ exists).

EDIT: I decided to look up a proof for this. It turns out lots of posts on SE just make the claim without giving a proof (or say the proof is too complex and just refer to Rockafeller's book). The complexity of the proof here: https://maunamn.wordpress.com/11-continuity-of-convex-functions/ suggests that I've missed something pretty important in my very short proof.